# Event triggers and Range Function - Run-time error

Tags: excel, vba, object, runtime-error

I have the following worksheet function saved in the Sheet1 (DataInput) module of VBA

```
Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Range)
    Set target = Range("F67")

    If target.Value = "YES" Then
        Call ThisWorkbook.Red_Macro_Text
    End If
End Sub
```

This code calls the following code in ThisWorkbook

```
Public Sub Red_Macro_Text()
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataInput").Range("B68").Value2 =  ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Text").Range("B3").Value2
End Sub
```

The purpose of the code is as follows:

1. The code uses an event trigger to watch for changes to worksheet ‘datainput’ cell F67.
2. Whenever the user selects ‘YES’ from a drop down menu in cell F67 it calls the subroutine in ThisWorkbook.
3. The code uses the range function to assign the value of 'text' worksheet B3 into 'datainput' worksheet B68 cell.

The trigger event does call the code and the content of B3 does get transferred to B68 however following this I then get the error message:

> Run-time error ‘-2147417848 (80010108)’: Automation error The object
>   invoked has disconnected from its clients.

Please note I do not want to use an IF statement in excel to achieve this as I am trying to automate the process in VBA.

I have been searching for a solution to this problem for some time without success.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem as I have reached the limit of my understanding!

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to `Set target = Range("F67")` because it is already retrieved as parameter `ByVal target As Range`

If you want to run the code only if F67 changes use the following instead:

```
Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("F67")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Parent.Range("F67").Value = "YES" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Red_Macro_Text
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

*Note that `Call` is not needed to call a macro.*

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("F67").Address Then
        If Target.Value = "YES" Then
            Call ThisWorkbook.Red_Macro_Text
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This fails if `Target` is more than one cell, therefore I suggested to use `Intersect`, so you end up with what I answered.